# Proof if $0\leq a,b<1$ then $a+b<1+ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

I need to prove that is $0\leq a,b<1$ then $a+b<1+ab$. What I did is see this is equivalent to $a+b-ab<1$. We have:

$a+b-ab=a+(1-a)b<a+(1-a)1=1$ as desired.

Is there a straightforward way to attack it (in the sense that when I solved it I wasn't 100% sure if the approach would work)

Comment: $a,b<1$ is enough for the inequality to hold. $a,b>1$ is also enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$(1-a)(1-b)=1-a-b+ab$$

Comment: Oh, this is even sweeter +1. Although I was looking at a broader technique which could be applied.

Comment: What is special about $(1-a)(1-b)?$ .......oh.......i can say that expression is greater than 0?

Comment: You got it @dc3rd . Each factor is greater than 0 as both $a$ and $b$ are positive and strictly less than 1.

Comment: @josh The fact $a,b$ are positive is not needed for the inequality to hold.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $1> a \geq 0$. Consider

$f(x) = 1 +ax - a -x = (1-a) + (a-1)x = (1-a)(1-x)$.

We have $0 <(1-x) \lesssim (1-a)(1-x)$.